# Repeat non-pivot column in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, dynamic, reporting-services, pivot-table, ssrs-2008-r2

[image]

Referring to the image, I would like to repeat the salesagent column after every few rows.  How do I do this in SSRS?

Note:  My report will have a start and end date parameter for customers to choose.  I will be using the date column for pivoting purposes.  If a customer chooses to run the report for six months, they will have plenty of date columns so they are requesting to repeat the non-pivoted header column every seven days/column.  Is it possible?

Let me know if more information is needed from me.

Comment: You can "freeze" the column like in Excel would that be more helpful?

Comment: Client prefer repeating the column, but that is one option I have considered.  Do you know how it will act if exported to Excel?